# Error converting Array to XML

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I am building an API. One of the functions returns a multi-dimensional array with a dynamic number of records. When a single records is returned my array2xml function works fine but when there is more than 1 I get the error "XML Parsing Error: junk after document element". I have included the function that should convert it to xml and the array in it's unconverted format below:

```
/* Setting XML header */
            @header ("content-type: text/xml charset=utf-8");

            /* Initializing the XML Object */
            $xml = new XmlWriter();
            $xml->openMemory();
            $xml->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
            $xml->startElement('callback');
            $xml->writeAttribute('xmlns:xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
            $xml->writeAttribute('xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation','schema.xsd');

            /* Function that converts each array element to an XML node */
            function write(XMLWriter $xml, $data){
                foreach($data as $key => $value){
                    if(is_array($value)){
                            $xml->startElement($key);
                            write($xml, $value);
                            $xml->endElement();
                            continue;
                    }
                    $xml->writeElement($key, $value);
                }
            }

            /* Calls previously declared function, passing our results array as parameter */
            write($xml, $data);

            /* Closing last XML node */
            $xml->endElement();

            /* Printing the XML */
            echo $xml->outputMemory(true);
```

The array being converted:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Scope_CH] => Intruder Alarm Systems (ACPO) Certified                                                             
            [Scope_ID] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Scope_CH] => CCTV Systems Approved                                                                               
            [Scope_ID] => 5
        )

)
```

The output if I remove the header from the xml creator is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<callback xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd"><Scope_CH>Intruder Alarm Systems (ACPO) Certified                                                             </Scope_CH><Scope_ID>1</Scope_ID></callback><Scope_CH>CCTV Systems Approved                                                                               </Scope_CH><Scope_ID>5</Scope_ID>
```

Comment: try removing the content-type header and seeing what it outputs

Comment: it returns the xml but doesn't close it and provides no key for each record so if we converted it back to array we would just have lots of repeated keys rather than a multidimensional array with an iteration

Comment: could you paste the exact output?

Comment: well there's you problem. for some reason, `XmlWriter endElement()` does not add ending xml tags. it is not outputting proper xml. what does `endelement()` do? I am not familiar with XmlWriter

Comment: I have no idea, that's just an xml converter I found that someone recommended. If you have a better one feel free to suggest :)